# Edit Modal properties inside sizes object not working

Tags: next.js, chakra-ui

I'm trying to set CSS property for the Chakra ui Modal component (in particular the dialog part), editing it at the theme level.
If I add property as baseStyle, it works, but inside sizes, somehow, no.
Any clue how to fix it?

```
import { type ComponentStyleConfig, defineStyle } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { createMultiStyleConfigHelpers } from '@chakra-ui/styled-system';

const helpers = createMultiStyleConfigHelpers(['dialog', 'header', 'body']);

const Modal = helpers.defineMultiStyleConfig({
  baseStyle: {
    header: {
      pb: 0,
      fontWeight: '500',
      fontSize: '1.125rem',
      lineHeight: '1.5rem',
    },
    body: {
      color: 'black',
      lineHeight: '1.25rem',
      fontSize: '0.875rem',
      fontWeight: '400',
    },
    sizes: {
      xs: {
        dialog: {
          mt: 0,
          maxHeight: 'auto',
        },
      },
      md: {
        dialog: {
          mt: 'auto',
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
        },
      },
    },
    variants: {},
    defaultProps: {
      size: 'md',
      variant: 'solid',
    },
  },
});

export default Modal as ComponentStyleConfig;
```

I've tried to edit the Modal of the Chakra UI library but it's not working.